# Error when trying to access a field in MATLAB structure

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run a loop over multiple files, by feeding the file names into a function. I have saved these file names as a structure using:

```
files=dir('testdata\*.siz');
nrows=size(files,1);
```

Now my loop is:

```
for i=1:nrows
filename=files.name{i};
Singapore(filename);
writetable(ans,'file.xls')
end
```

However, I get the error: 

"Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by more reference blocks is an error."

I found that the error is in

```
filename=files.name{1};
```

but everywhere I've searched tells me to use { } to access fields in a structure. I also have tried other types of brackets in vain.

Additional Information:

'files' is the name of the structure

'name' is the first column field within 'files' containing the file names in inverted commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing the files struct wrong, you need:

```
files(i).name
```

The {} is for accessing cell arrays.

You should also use `ii` (or similar) instead of `i` as your indexing variable since `i` is a already Matlab variable (imaginary unit).

Comment: Got it! Thanks! So for the loop I did 
    filename=files(i).name, 
and it worked

Comment: I guess that it is not recommended to use `i` as a loop variable, but I have never got any troubles with that. The imaginary unit should be referenced via `1i` according to Matlabs recommendation. Further, in case the function is short the scope is small enough. I would say it is the same with Matlab as any language there. The larger the scope is the longer name of the variable. The only difference is that the scope of the loop variable in matlab ends when the function ends.

Comment: @JoelWong Consider accepting the answer if it helped ;)

Comment: @patrick - To be honest I have used i in the past and I never ran into problems either.  I only mentioned it to be complete! :)

Comment: @patrik [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) explains why you should not use `i` or `j` as variable names. It's both because you will get into trouble when using complex numbers and it is time consuming to overwrite a built-in function.

Comment: @Adriaan I do not disagree with that it is bad practice to use `i` and `j` as loop variables. However the overhead for this is minimal and the errors that can happen comes from already bad practice like not using `1i` and `1j` for imaginary unit. Further `1i` and `ii` does almost look the same, so I would rather recommend to use `k, n, m` in case short names are wanted. Apart from that, I prefer descriptive names like `fileI`. This is short, hard to mix up with something and gives a clear understanding about what the variable is supposed to represent.